# collection sorting

Tags: sorting, collections, groovy

The GDK docs indicate that [Collection.sort(Comparator comparator)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort%28java.util.Comparator%29) does not change the collection it is called on, but the code below indicates otherwise. Is this a bug in the implementation, error in the docs, or a misunderstanding on my part?

```
class ISO3LangComparator implements Comparator<Locale> {

    int compare(Locale locale1, Locale locale2) {
        locale1.ISO3Language <=> locale2.ISO3Language
    }
}

List<Locale> locales = [Locale.FRENCH, Locale.ENGLISH]
def sortedLocales = locales.sort(new ISO3LangComparator())

// This assertion fails
assert locales[0] == frenchLocale
```

Comment: I think the documentation is wrong :-( `sort` corrupting the collection is probably my least favourite thing in groovy...

Comment: Added it to the JIRA http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4742

Comment: Thanks Tim, I've added the code above to the issue

Comment: @tim_yates do you have a link for the webpages that show you the GDK source code? I think they're on GitHub somewhere. Should be pretty easy to subit a patch for this - just clone the collection, then sort the clone instead of `this`

Comment: Groovy is currently under svn at codehaus. There are movements to get it across to a git repo I believe, but at the moment the best you can get to is http://svn.groovy.codehaus.org/browse/groovy/trunk/groovy/groovy-core/

Comment: @tim_yates thanks, but that link doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Don Might just be quicker to grab the source direct `svn co https://svn.codehaus.org/groovy/trunk/groovy/groovy-core` fisheye struggles at the best of times, and it seems to be down atm :-(

Comment: Updated link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4742

Answer (score 2):

the documentation states:

> If the Collection is a List, it is
>   sorted in place and returned.
>   Otherwise, the elements are first
>   placed into a new list which is then
>   sorted and returned - leaving the
>   original Collection unchanged.

which is reflected in the implementation of the sort() method

```
public static <T> List<T> sort(Collection<T> self, Comparator<T> comparator) {
  List<T> list = asList(self);
  Collections.sort(list, comparator);
  return list;
}
```

the asList method looks whether the given collection is an instanceof java.util.List. If yes, it returns the reference, if not it returns a new java.util.ArrayList instance.

since you are using the [] syntax you are implicitly working with an instance of java.util.List.